# How make better Rails I18n (sorting and search by translation)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, localization, internationalization

Now I have model `Territory - id, territory_title_locale_key` in my database

And I have `en.yml` and `ru.yml` files with translations. In future, i want to add more locales. Now I show value - `I18n.t("translate_path.#{territory.territory_title_locale_key}")`

But I can't fast search territories by title's value and order them by title.

I see variant:

Change database to `Territory - id, title, en, ru, es, ...` and always type `Territory.where(my_condition).select("#{I18n.locale} as title")` (for each new locale I must add column to database).

Or Create additional table `Translations` with polymorph references, translations and locale_ids.

How to make it better?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the globalize gem, it does what you're looking for.
https://github.com/globalize/globalize

Example:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 translates :title, :text
end

I18n.locale = :en
post.title # => Globalize rocks!

I18n.locale = :he
post.title # => גלובאלייז2 שולט!
```